# Netbeans Profile JUnit 4 problem

Tags: netbeans, junit, profiler

I have a unit test that takes 200 sec to run.  I am trying to use NetBeans profiler to speed it up.  But the profiler doesn't run the unit test.  It just creates an object of the test and exits.  Doesn't run the actual test methods or @Before / @After methods.

This is a maven project with surefire and junit 4.

And partial output is below.

```
Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140, timeout 10 seconds (Protocol version: 9)
Profiler Agent: Established local connection with the tool

-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.cris.puzzle.solvers.SudokuSolverTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.031 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Profiler Agent: Connection with agent closed
Profiler Agent: Connection with agent closed
Profiler Agent: Initializing...
Profiler Agent: Options: >C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.8/profiler3/lib,5140,10<
Profiler Agent: Initialized succesfully
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 14 seconds
```

Does anyone know how to make it work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround. Move your test code into application code temporarily. Profile it and improve it. Once finished, move back your improved code to JUnit code.

Comment: Hmm, yeah but I wanted to know how to profile through JUnits. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, what is your OS, but in Win 7 (and probably also Vista), there is the problem with JUnit that it needs to have write permission to its directory (which is in default installation of NetBeans in Program files, and there it has not this access). But in that case, you would probably have problems with JUnit itself from the beginning.